# Create Power BI Slicer based on column headers

Tags: powerbi

I have a table where the first three columns are considered parameters to sort on. Think of it as CLASS, SYSTEM, GROUP or equivalent. All text entries but many can be the same in each column to give a sense of organization.

Then the remaining 'N' columns have the actual data that pertain to that CLASS-SYSTEM-GROUP row. Each column in this 'value' part is intended to showcase a unique set of values.

Is is possible to create a slicer of just the value columns when the names of the headers for those columns may change? I mean how do you dynamically change the slicer to equal the shown value columns?

The goal is to give the user the capability to always show the CLASS-SYSTEM-GROUP columns (lets call them a-b-c) but dynamically show or hide the value columns (lets call them d-e-f...) depending on a slicer entry to show a direct comparison of column d versus column e across the parameters defined in columns a-b-c.

I cannot figure out how to properly use the Table.ColumnNames approach....

Comment: A typical solution in such situations is to unpivot data so that the column headers become a data column. What prevents you from using such approach?

Comment: @RADO doesn’t that require that the first column before unpivoting to be the unique identifier of some sort? I have basically a three column way to group the data. Not one column that is a row ID or tag of some sort. Thanks.

Comment: If you post your data sample, I might be able to give you a better advice.